# AWS WAF Rate Limit by Request URL Component

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to start by saying that I'm a *total* newcomer to AWS.

I'm investigating using AWS WAF for dynamic rate limiting based on a component of the request URL. The AWS website has a tutorial for doing this by IP address, but I have no idea if it can be modified to do what I need.

So, with that in mind, please tell me what, if any, of the following is actually possible:

- Rate limit by a component of the URL (an API key in this case)
- Determine limit dynamically (different behaviour for different keys)
- Perform some non-blocking action in the first instance of exceeding
  the limit, then block if the limit is exceeded consistently
- Log both of the above actions and do something with the outputted logs (i.e. forward them somewhere)

Again, I'm not looking for detailed how-tos here as they would probably warrant seperate questions - just want to know if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

[API Gateway](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/welcome.html) is probably the right fit for what you are looking to implement. It has throttling implemented out of the box.

Take a look at [API Gateway Usage Plans](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-usage-plans.html) for implementation details for your specific use case.

Comment: Thanks, this is much closer to what's needed than WAF. Unfortunately it still seems to lack a lot of the flexibility we need, especially around the handling of our API keys (it seems to assume use of Amazon's key system). We're still evaluating at the moment but it's looking like we'll have to DIY something.